# reactjs clean inputs after form is submitted

Tags: reactjs

currently i have one problem in my forms i cant clear inputs after form is submitted..
I have two files for input and form:

**form-hook.js**

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from 'react';

const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INPUT_CHANGE':
      let formIsValid = true;
      for (const inputId in state.inputs) {
        if (!state.inputs[inputId]) {
          continue;
        }
        if (inputId === action.inputId) {
          formIsValid = formIsValid && action.isValid;
        } else {
          formIsValid = formIsValid && state.inputs[inputId].isValid;
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        inputs: {
          ...state.inputs,
          [action.inputId]: { value: action.value, isValid: action.isValid }
        },
        isValid: formIsValid
      };
    case 'SET_DATA':
      return {
        inputs: action.inputs,
        isValid: action.formIsValid
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const useForm = (initialInputs, initialFormValidity) => {
  const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    inputs: initialInputs,
    isValid: initialFormValidity
  });

  const inputHandler = useCallback((id, value, isValid) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'INPUT_CHANGE',
      value: value,
      isValid: isValid,
      inputId: id
    });
  }, []);

  const setFormData = useCallback((inputData, formValidity) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_DATA',
      inputs: inputData,
      formIsValid: formValidity
    });
  }, []);

  return [formState, inputHandler, setFormData];
};
```

And here i got one Input.js file:

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';

import { validate } from '../../util/validators';

const inputReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.val,
        isValid: validate(action.val, action.validators)
      };
    case 'TOUCH': {
      return {
        ...state,
        isTouched: true
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const Input = props => {
  const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer, {
    value: props.initialValue || '',
    isTouched: false,
    isValid: props.initialValid || false
  });

  const { id, onInput, clearInputs } = props;
  const { value, isValid } = inputState;

  useEffect(() => {
    onInput(id, value, isValid);
  }, [id, value, isValid, onInput]);

  const changeHandler = event => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'CHANGE',
      val: event.target.value,
      validators: props.validators
    });
  };

  const touchHandler = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'TOUCH'
    });
  };

  const element =
    props.element === 'input' ? (
      <input
        id={props.id}
        type={props.type}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        onBlur={touchHandler}
        value={inputState.value}
        maxLength={props.maxlength}
      />
    ) : (
      <textarea
        id={props.id}
        rows={props.rows || 3}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        onBlur={touchHandler}
        value={inputState.value}
      />
    );

  return (
    <div
      className={`form-control ${!inputState.isValid &&
        inputState.isTouched &&
        'form-control--invalid'}`}
    >
      <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
      {element}
      {!inputState.isValid && inputState.isTouched && <p>{props.errorText}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

My problem here is that i can't access this inputState, it looks like the value is stored in it...
And this is just an example how is this used in my components and this is functional programing in reactjs..

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

import { Text, LanguageContext } from '../../lang/containers/Language';
import Input from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Input';
import Button from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Button';
import ErrorModal from '../../shared/components/UIElements/ErrorModal';
import {
    VALIDATOR_EMAIL
} from '../../shared/util/validators';
import { useForm } from '../../shared/hooks/form-hook';
import { useHttpClient } from '../../shared/hooks/http-hook';

const NewSletter = () => {
    const { dictionary } = useContext(LanguageContext);
    const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
    const [joined, setJoined] = useState(false);

    const [formState, inputHandler] = useForm(
        {
          email: {
            value: '',
            isValid: false
          }  
        },
        false
    );
    
    const newsletterSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
          const responseData = await sendRequest(
            'http://localhost:5000/api/users/newsletter',
            'POST',
            JSON.stringify({
              email: formState.inputs.email.value,
            }),
            {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          );

          if(responseData.message == 'subscribed'){
            setJoined(true);
            //here i need to clean all inputs in this form
          }

        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
    };

    return (
    <>
      <ErrorModal error={error ? <Text tid={error}/> : null} onClear={clearError} />
      <div className="newsletter-bg">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="newsletter-bg-title"><Text tid="newsletter"/></div>

                    <div className="space10px"></div>

                    <form className="newsletter-form" onSubmit={newsletterSubmit}>
                    <Input
                        element="input"
                        id="email"
                        type="email"
                        label={<Text tid="auth_lang4" />}
                        validators={[VALIDATOR_EMAIL()]}
                        errorText={<Text tid="auth_lang5" />}
                        onInput={inputHandler}
                    />
                    <Button type="submit" disabled={!formState.isValid}>
                    <Text tid="add"/>
                    </Button>
                    {joined === true ? <div className="biltenmsg"> <span style={{color: 'green'}}><Text tid="joinedsletter"/></span> </div> : null}
                    </form>
                </div>
      </div>
    </>
    );
};

export default NewSletter;
```

I also tried serveral examples from here like reset() and others things, also tried to change useForm  things but i couldnt delete value because it read value from input.js file in inputState how i figured... I also tryed with setformdata and some others examples but i didnt solve this problem.. Best regards.

Comment: ok, you are design a form hook. When you say after form is submitted, where exactly you mean "after"? Seems to me inside `newsletterSubmit` you can get the `formState.inputs` ?

Comment: Yes i specified the part where i need to clean inputs.. I also tried with formState.inputs.email.value = ''; but this dont solve my problem.. How i configured the values are stored in input.js in inputState that i cant access..

Comment: you can't clean anything by doing assignment directly, everything goes with your handler, ex. call `inputHandler(...)`. That's the only way from `useForm` point of view, because state gets updated by dispatch only :)

Comment: thanks for help i will try to fix this..

Answer (score 1):

You can only update inputState by dispatch only

```
    const inputReducer = (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE':
          return {
            ...state,
            value: action.val,
            isValid: validate(action.val, action.validators)
          };
        case 'TOUCH': {
          return {
            ...state,
            isTouched: true
          };
        }
        case 'RESET': {
          return {
              value: action.value,
              isTouched: action.isTouched,
              isValid: action.isValid
          };
        }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

then

```
      dispatch({
         type: 'RESET',
         value: props.initialValue || '',
         isTouched: false,
         isValid: props.initialValid || false
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, can u give me and example how should i use this?

Comment: I updated my ansert I forgot to add the type: 'RESET'

Comment: This is what i got currently with your example : https://pastebin.com/rBCw3dVE , if i correctly update my code with your example but this didnt solve my problem..

Comment: you shoul remove dispatch  type: 'RESET', in const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer, {
    type: 'RESET',
    value: props.initialValue || '',
    isTouched: false,
    isValid: props.initialValid || false
  });


............call ---->>>  dispatch({
         type: 'RESET',
         value: props.initialValue || '',
         isTouched: false,
         isValid: props.initialValid || false
      });
in your submit function

Comment: I found one guy and he solved my problem, but im really thankfull for your help thanks ;]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much problem in your `formReducer` which got used by `useForm` and inside you defined a `inputHandler` that is must-have to get any `input` work. However your `Input` is overly complicated IMHO.

Attached is an example `useForm`

```js
const useForm = (props = {}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState(props))

  const change = useCallback((payload) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'change', payload })
  }, [])

  const validate = useCallback((payload) => {
    if (!state.validate) return
    dispatch({ type: 'validate', payload: payload || state.values })
  }, [state])

  const submit = useCallback((payload) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'submit', payload })
  }, [])

  const onChange = useCallback(e => {
    const target = e.target
    const payload = { [target.name]: target.value }
    change(payload)
    validate(payload)
  }, [change, validate])

  const onSubmit = useCallback(e => {
    if (e) e.preventDefault()
    submit(state.values)
  }, [submit, state.values])

  /**
   * @typedef {object} useFormObject
   * @property {string} name        Form name
   * @property {object} values      Form values
   * @property {func} change        Form change function
   * @property {object} handlers    Form events
   * @property {func} handlers.onChange Event upon input change
   * @property {func} handlers.onSubmit Event upon form submit
   * @property {func} validate      Form validate function
   * @property {object} errors      Form errors
   * @property {bool} error         Form in error
   */
  return {
    name: state.name,
    values: state.values,
    change,
    handlers: {
      onChange,
      onSubmit
    },
    validate,
    errors: state.errors,
    error: hasError(state.errors),
  }
}

export default useForm
```

and the usage is

```js
  const { values, handlers, errors } = useForm({ initialValues })
```

and then every input widget is about

```js
  <input value={values.abc} onChange={handlers.onChange} />
```

You can see there's no need for another level of `reducer` inside `input`, because both `value` and `onChange` are almost "read-only" properties from input point of view.

For completeness, `reducer` is attached here.

```js
import hasError from './hasError'

const defaultState = {
  values: {},
  errors: {},
  watchers: {}
}

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  let payload = {}
  if (action && action.payload) {
    payload = action.payload
  }

  const watchers = state.watchers || {}
  const watch = state.watch || (() => { })
  const validate = state.validate || (() => { })
  const { onSubmitted } = watchers
  let errors
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'change':
      watch(action.type, payload)
      return {
        ...state,
        values: {
          ...state.values,
          ...payload
        }
      }
    case 'validate':
      errors = validate(payload, action.type)
      watch(action.type, errors)
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: {
          ...state.errors,
          ...errors
        }
      }
    case 'submit':
      errors = validate(payload, action.type)
      watch('validation', errors)
      if (hasError(errors)) {
        return {
          ...state,
          errors
        }
      }
      if (onSubmitted) {
        onSubmitted(state.values)
      }
      return state
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

Comment: Thanks for examples, but i really dont know how should i update my code with your examples.. In others pages i used like push , but in this just after form is submitted i just need to clean inputs.. Is there any simple example so i can update my code? Best regards @ I also posted a newsletter.js thats example how i used my form and thats all component..